# syncronous http request in node.js

Tags: node.js

I use node.js as a client that makes some http requests. I want to use http in syncronous manner. I know node.js has synchronous versions of file system apis. Is there something for http also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a synchronous function for doing http requests in Node.js. There are only a few synchronous function in Node, mostly which are related to file operations.

You can use promises however to achieve this, but looks to me more complicated that actually writing a few lines of asynchronous code. ( example of promises libraries: https://github.com/medikoo/deferred or https://github.com/megakorre/promise ).

You should really try to write asynchronous code in Node, since Node is all about that (async).

Comment: thanks, but how would promises help here, aren't they just helping to write asynchronous code more explicitly?

Comment: You can use Fibers or Promises to write code that looks more like synchronous, but I really really advise you just to use async code. It's easier and faster.